# Why does this quintic curve use taylor series of exp?

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, curves, interpolation

I'm trying to reverse engineer an interpolation used for animation. It seems to use 5 coefficients of the taylor series of $f(x) =e^{x}$.

```
import math
import numpy as np

def exp_taylor_series(x):
    return [x**n / math.factorial(n) for n in range(5)]

def interp(t, p0, p1, v0, v1, t0, t1):
    """    
    t : The time at which to calculate the interpolated value.
    p0 : The position of the first point.
    p1 : The position of the second point.
    v0 : The velocity at the first point.
    v1 : The velocity at the second point.
    t0 : The time at the first point.
    t1 : The time at the second point.
    Returns: The interpolated value of the point at time t.
    """
    # Get x at known point p1 with slope m1 at time t1
    # Use known point p0 with slope m0 at time t0 as offset
    p = p1 - p0 - v0 * (t1 - t0)
    v = v1 - v0
    y = np.array([p, v, 0.0])
    s = exp_taylor_series(t1 - t0)
    A = np.array([
        [s[4], s[3], s[2]],
        [s[3], s[2], s[1]],
        [s[2], s[1], s[0]],
    ])
    x = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A), y) # x = A^-1 ⋅ y
    # Do the inverse of previous
    # Solve for y at current time t to get slope and position
    # Use known point p0 with slope m0 at time t0 as offset
    s = exp_taylor_series(t - t0)
    A = np.array([
        [s[4], s[3], s[2]],
        [s[3], s[2], s[1]],
        [s[2], s[1], s[0]],
    ])
    y = np.dot(A, x) # y = A ⋅ x
    p = y[0]
    v = y[1]
    pt = p + p0 + v0 * (t - t0)
    vt = v + v0
    return pt
```

For $p_0 = 0, p_1 = 1, m_0 = 0,  m_1 = 0, t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1$, it gives a curve that [looks a lot like a Hermite Spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVPXk.png).

Something notable that I saw is that the difference between the two curves is [a quadradic equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Krs.png) with the form of $d(x) = 2 - 4x + 2x^2 + 5.95499956\times10^{-15}x -3.53508224\times10^{-16}x $

What is this matrix supposed to represent and does it have a name?

**Edit**

The curve is in fact a scaled and translated quintic curve which passes through $(0, 0)$ with a slope of $m_0$ and through $(1, 1)$ with a slope of $m_1$.

I did some testing because I wondered if normalizing the curve could reduce the number of variables at play. To achieve this, I made a different function where $t \in [0, 1]$ and $p_0 = 0, p_1=1$ leaving only the start and end velocities as free variables and they can be seen as slopes now.

I was able to reduce the function to a simple matrix multiplication and get the same curve.

The matrix comes from starting with the taylor series expansion of exp(x) at 1
$$
s(x) = \left(\frac{x^0}{0!}, \frac{x^1}{1!}, ..., \frac{x^n}{n!}, ...\right)
$$
Constructing the a matrix to satisfy $y = Ax$ using the first 5 terms for solving a linear equation. The construction is odd to me. I do not know why it's done this way.
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
s_4 & s_3 & s_2\\
s_3 & s_2 & s_1\\
s_2 & s_1 & s_0
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{24} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{6}  & \frac{1}{2} & 1           \\
\frac{1}{2}  & 1           & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since this matrix construction is constant and no longer dependent on different values of $t_0$ and $t_1$, the expensive computation of the inverse can be calculated and stored.

$$
A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
72 & -48 & 12 \\
-48 & 30 & -6 \\
12 & -6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We normally get y by using range values for position, velocity and acceleration. However, thanks to our assumptions this is greatly simplified.

$$
y = \begin{bmatrix}
p_1 - p_0 - m_0 * (t_1 - t_0)  \\
m_1 - m_0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 - m_0  &
m_1 - m_0 &
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now our formula for $x$ is

$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
72 & -48 & 12 \\
-48 & 30 & -6 \\
12 & -6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - m_0  &
m_1 - m_0 &
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At this point the expensive bit of computing the inverse matrix for the linear equation is done and the interpolation can now use it to get new values to x with $y = A_t x$. Where $A_t$ is constructed again with $s(x)$ at $t$.

$$
y_t = A_t x =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{t^4}{24} & \frac{t^3}{6} & \frac{t^2}{2} \\
\frac{t^3}{6} & \frac{t^2}{2} & t \\
\frac{t^2}{2} & t & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
72 & -48 & 12 \\
-48 & 30 & -6 \\
12 & -6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - m_0  &
m_1 - m_0 &
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then reconstruct the position, velocity and acceleration from $y_t$ using the reverse process.
$$
p_t = y_{t_0} + p_0 + m_0 \dot (t - t_0) = y_{t_0} + m_0 t
$$
$$
m_t = y_{t_1} + m_0
$$

I don't have the work for this, but using the `polyval` function in python, I can create a degree 5 polynomial curve and this lets me skip finding $y_t$ and directly get the first three coefficients to which I add $m_0$ and $p_0 = 0$.

$$
c = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1^4}{4!} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1^3}{3!} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1^2}{2!}
\end{bmatrix}
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{24} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
72 & -48 & 12 \\
-48 & 30 & -6 \\
12 & -6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - m_0  &
m_1 - m_0 &
0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -8 & 6 \\
-2 & 5 & -3 \\
0.5 & -1 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - m_0  & 
m_1 - m_0 &
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Instead of adding the coefficients after the fact, I re-arange the matrix and x to look like:

$$
c = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & -1 & 3 \\
     5 & 3 & -8 \\
    -3 & -3 & 6 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 & m_0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which is enough to model the curve. The simplified code looks like this

```
import numpy as np

def interp_simple(m0, m1, t):
    """
    Interpolate for a Quintic curve which passes through (0, 0) with a slope of m0
    and through (1, 1) with a slope of m1.
    Acceleration, jerk and snap are hardcoded and come from a strange taylor series of the exp function
    
    t : Interpolation value between 0 and 1.
    m0 : The slope at t=0.
    m1 : The slope at t=1.
    Returns: The interpolated value for value t.
    """
    M = np.array([
        [-2., -1.,  3.],
        [ 5.,  3., -8.],
        [-3., -3.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]
    ])
    return np.polyval(np.dot(M, np.array([m1, m0, 1.0])), t)

def interp_simplified(t, p0, p1, v0, v1, t0, t1):
    """    
    t : The time at which to calculate the interpolated value.
    p0 : The position of the first point.
    p1 : The position of the second point.
    v0 : The velocity at the first point.
    v1 : The velocity at the second point.
    t0 : The time at the first point.
    t1 : The time at the second point
    Returns: The interpolated value of the point at time t.
    """
    # Catch a few singularities
    if p0 == p1:
        return p0
    if t0 == t1:
        return (p0 + p1) / 2
    # Get the ranges
    pr = p1 - p0
    tr = t1 - t0
    vr = pr / tr
    # Interpolate like if p0=0, p1=1, t0=0 and t1=1, duration will be 0
    # Also determine the slopes from the speeds
    return interp_simple(v0 / vr, v1 / vr, t / tr) * pr + p0
```

[The curve fits perfectly with these coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXijg.png)

I still would like to know why the taylor series for $e^x$ is used as it would let me know how the higher order coefficients are used.

Comment: I've dug more into this and while I do not know why the taylor series is used, I can say that the curve is a quintic curve.

The computation can be simplified by normalizing the time and position range to 0-1. The velocities must also be scaled down by the ratio position and time ranges. The resulting curve can then be scaled back up

This then becomes a linear equation to find the coefficients where
    x = [m1, m0, 1.0]
    M = [
        [-2., -1.,  3.],
        [ 5.,  3., -8.],
        [-3., -3.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]
    ]